# GPG4WIN Keys and Transferring them

Tags: encryption, pgp, public-key-encryption, openpgp

I have installed www.gpg4win.org and have generated a keys that will allow me to both sign and encrypt files. On windows it uses the (KDE) / Kleopatra Certificate Manager - Version 2.1.0.

What is the best way to save/keep the keys ?

Ideally I would like to save them on a USB stick to keep them safe and also then be able to use them on other computers as I switch between laptop (Ubuntu) desktop(Windows).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer:

- Open Kleopatra
- Select The Certificate
- Export Certificate (This is your Public Key)
- Export Secret Key (Select ASCII ARMOR - if you want it ASCII readable)

Indeed if you take the keys onto a usb drive (or indeed as mentioned any partition) it is wise to use some software like truecrypt to protect them.

Answer (score 1):

The most secure tactic is to keep them on an encrypted partition across every system you use the keys. USB HDD etc.

True crypt could take care of this for you.

Otherwise, lets come down to the reality of the situation. Is your info really THAT important?

Unless you want to do this for educational purposes, please try to evaluate how secure your 2 gigs of porn and personal journal really needs to be.

Comment: Lol Scandalist....its more just an exercise for me. I would still like to know if its possible though =)

Comment: In that case yes, encrypt every partition where the keys are present. Otherwise, anybody with a SATA to usb adapter or a live Linux distro could jack those keys no problem.

Comment: While I'm all for caution -- all of my disks are encrypted (linux) and I would revoke a key if someone got their hands on it -- your comments are misleading. While "anybody with a ... live Linux distro" could *get at* encrypted GPG private keys, they most certainly would not be able to do anything with them any time soon.